# Custom Html Wordpress Login/Register Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, redirect

> I have a custom login/register and forgot password html template pages I
>   recently
>   purchased. I want to only work through these pages instead of the
>   wp-login/register pages. I modified the login page a bit and I can
>   login perfectly if I enter the correct information into the form.

My problem persist when I enter a blank form or incorrect information into the form. The page gets redirected to the standard wp-login.php.

Is there a way to not have the page redirect instead show some text maybe stating "the information you entered is incorrect or empty try again" ?

This is the custom code i have implemented now below.

```
      <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://example.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
            </form>

     <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Log In" class="button button-fill color-black text-thiny">
```

> FYI My template/html files are located in my root publichtml folder instead of wp-content

Comment: Could you alter the script to return a response, and then use an Ajax call to submit the form instead?

Comment: Im looked into ajax implementation Im not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set a login form in wordpress is:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo wp_login_url('URL_TO_REDIRECT_AFTER_LOGGED'); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="log">
    <input type="password" name="pwd">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" value="Login" >
</form>
```

The form action is the URL when you log sucessfully. Is important to keep the inputs ´name´ fields because these will get wordpress as login data

Comment: The page continues to redirect even with incorrect info or blank form

Answer (score 0):

Change wp-login.php to echo some sort of response that can be used to verify, then control what happens yourself (redirect/error msg) with an ajax call

```
function myCallBack(response) {
    if(response == "success") {
        //Handle login redirect
    } else {
        //Handle error message to user
    }
}

$('#wp-submit').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#loginform');

    var serializedData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-login.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData,
        success: myCallBack
    });

}
```

Comment: Am I adding to my functions.php or to a js file?

Comment: You can do this in a JS file then use wp_enqueue_script in functions.php to load it